# HTTP Put Request Specification for Netflix Exhibitor API

Tags: rest, http, apache-zookeeper, netflix

I am facing some issue with making a HTTP Put call to a server running Netflix Exhibitor. Call is successful when it is made without data, but when ever I want to post some data, call fails 415 error.
API documentation says following about format of data
**Argument  BinaryString* (i.e. the node data)
*BinaryString is a JSON string consisting of hex values. E.g. “AF1023DD”.**

Documentation is available [here](https://github.com/Netflix/exhibitor/wiki/REST-Modify)
(Please look for createOrUpdateNode details)

My question is what should I pass for "BinaryString is a JSON string consisting of hex values".

I tried with ContentType:application/octet-stream , with some binarydata, but it failed.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution for this. Exhibitor API call needs to have content type as application-json, while content should be hex string.
So

```
{"Key":"Value"}
```

needs to go as

```
7b224b6579223a2256616c7565227d
```

with this I am able to make PUT call successfully.

Comment: sample curl 

`curl --location --request PUT 'http://localhost:8400/exhibitor/v1/explorer/znode/config/PostgresVerticalSharding/spring.post-datasource.url' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data "$(echo -n 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5434/postgres' | xxd -ps -c 256)"`